# Finding Location of matrices within a structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I am importing an RGB image `U` of the stars and doing the following:

```
im=rgb2gray(U);
img=(im>200);
BW=im2bw(img,0);
L=bwlabeln(BW,18);
b=regionprops(L,'PixelList');
```

The goal of this program is to find the largest and most prominent stars in this picture of hundreds of stars. `b` is a 2566x1 struct array that contains all the points with a value greater than 200. If a certain connected region within the image contains multiple values over 200, b will store a coordinate matrix of these points. Otherwise, it will only store a single coordinate pair.

I need a way to find all the rows within `b` that contain matrices? If possible, a way to find all the rows within `b` that contain matrices that contain 30 or more points?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) function to apply a function to each element in an array. Note that this is just a shorter way of writing a loop.

In this case you'd need to apply the function `size(b(i).PixelList, 1) > 30` to each element `i` of the struct array `b`:

```
m = arrayfun(@(x)size(x.PixelList, 1) > 1, b)
```

This is identical to:

```
m = false(size(b));
for i=1:numel(b)
   m(i) = size(b(i).PixelList, 1) > 30;
end
```

The matrix `m` is a logical array, you can use it to index as `b(m)`. You can also get indices using `find(m)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you also include `'Area'` in the [properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#buoixjn-1-properties) calculated by `regionprops`, you'll already have the number of pixels in each component:

```
b=regionprops(L,'PixelList','Area');
idx = [b.Area] >= 30;
```